# Angular 2 BrowserDomAdapter error after upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript

Working on upgrading from RC2 to final in our app.  I've been having a recurring issue though, and can't find a workaround.

We have a need to pull data from the value of an input element outside of the Angular app, and push new values back to it as well.  So, we use BrowserDomAdapter to basically query for the element to get and set the value.

The error I get is :
browser_adapter.js:13Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Am I missing something from the upgrade that I missed on BrowserDomAdapter class or failing that, is there a better way to tackle my objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DomAdapter was dropped: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7561

I believe that was around RC3 or RC4.

On the other hand, according the other github thread, the DomAdapter was never intended as a public api.

Comment: I thought that might have been the case, but couldn't find anything to definitively say that.  The service in question is being dropped anyway, just trying to be thorough during my upgrade process.

Thanks for the help!